# How to make Toolbar overlay and be immersed?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, toolbar, android-immersive

I want to make my app be immersed seems like this following reader app, but it doesn't work as I wanted, can someone give me idea?

## Normal

When normal, the toolbar and the status is hidden.

## Pull the status

When pull the status, the status appears.
[Pull](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmgMI.png)

## Click in content

When click in the content, both of status and toolbar shows with elegant animation.
[Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdMvO.png)

Here is my code.

```
private void hideStatus() {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

And use `handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed()` to delay. But it works with out any animation.
Then I add `<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>`, but not work.

Here is my Layout code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ctl_indoor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_indoor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

PS: Sorry, my English is bad.

Comment: Use CoordinatorLayout

Comment: Thank you, but I just use CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: I think you need to specify scroll behavior, there is an abstract class you have to implement

Answer (score 0):

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

put into your layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
tools:context=".LauncherActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Comment: Thanks, but it still not works, the bool bar is still exists.